# How to compare datetime in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Background:

I want to show the time and date uptill only 1 week. After that I want to show only date.

I want to do something like this. (This doesn't work)

```
{% if greenboard.datetime|timesince >= "1 week" %}
    {{greenboard.datetime.date}}<br />
{% else %}
    {{greenboard.datetime|timesince}} ago
{% endif %}
```

EDIT:
Hi, even then with the editing all i get is the time along with all the parameters..i.e, date time . what should be the templatetag? as of now using this

`{{ greenboard.datetime|timesince_threshold:2 }}`

which gives exact time it is posted and tried using

`{{ greenboard.datetime|timesince }}` 
which gives no. of weeks and days. still not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timesince` is a simple wrapper around `django.utils.timesince` function. The easiest solution for your problem would be to write a custom filter:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django import template
from django.utils.timesince import timesince

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def timesince_threshold(value, days=7):
    """
    return timesince(<value>) if value is more than <days> old. Return value otherwise
    """

    if datetime.now() - value < timedelta(days=days):
        return timesince(value)
    else:
        return value
timesince_threshold.is_safe = False
```

Comment: Hi the filter is giving a error "Caught TypeError while rendering: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'type'"

Comment: Hi,
it worked like charm with small tweek
`if datetime.now() - value < timedelta(days=days):`
as it is giving out negative days. this solved the problem
thanks Secator

Comment: Hi can you tell me why you added `timesince_threshold.is_safe = False` at the end please?